# Reference local file image file in HTML

Tags: html

I am looking for suggestions on how to reference a local image file in HTML.  The HTML code will only ever be used locally and never be published on a network of any type.  I find that this code

```
<img src="file://l:/Test FFHP data/1042545.tif">
```

works well in Internet Explorer and Edge.  It does not work at all with Chrome or FireFox.

Please give me some direction.  I am hoping my users will be able to use their preferred browser.

Comment: If this is only for your local environment why don't you lock down the browser they use?

Comment: I could but it is nice to be flexible with the user community.

Comment: Consider also the utility in coding-in fixed, absolute paths. I could not run your code without modification, since I do not have an L drive. By using relative paths, you specifiy the location of resources relatively (or, as compared to the path of the running file). If the above was instead changed to `<img src='1042545.tif'>` and the image file was put in the same directory as the html one, the problem goes away and everyone can play.